# Прорисовка границ одного SVG-элемента при прокрутке страницы, когда в одном path несколько подпатчей

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, анимация, svg-animation

У меня есть SVG-элемент, который я анимирую c привязкой к прокрутке страницы. Вот пример такой анимации:

```js
var path = document.querySelectorAll('path'), 
        percentScroll;
$(path).each(function(){
  this.style.strokeDasharray = this.getTotalLength();
  this.style.strokeDashoffset = this.getTotalLength();
});
window.onscroll = function(){
  var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
var viewportTopX = $(window).scrollTop();
var viewportBottomX = viewportTopX + viewportHeight;
var elementHeight = $('#content').outerHeight();
var elementTopX = $('#content').offset().top;
var elementBottomX = elementTopX + elementHeight;
var percentScroll = (viewportBottomX - elementTopX) / ((viewportHeight + elementHeight) / 100);
  //console.log('%', 1 - percentScroll);
  foo = window.pageYOffset / (document.body.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight)
  //console.log('window', foo)
  $(path).each(function(){
    //console.log('math', Math.floor(this.getTotalLength() * (1 - foo)))
    this.style.strokeDashoffset = Math.floor(this.getTotalLength() * (1 - foo));
  });
};

//прогресс
let x = $('.progress');
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
  let st = $(window).scrollTop();
  let sa = $(document).height();
  let sb = $(window).height();
  let dd = Math.ceil(100 * (st / (sa - sb)));
  x.css({width : dd + '%'})
})
```

```css
body {margin: 0; height: 3000px;}
.progress {position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 0%; height: 5px; background-color: red;}
.progress::after {content: "Крутим вниз"; white-space: nowrap; position: absolute; top: 15px; left: 15px;}

#svg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress"></div><!--прогресс-->

<div id="content">
<svg id="svg" width="280px" height="280px" viewBox="0 0 1046 1280">
<g transform="translate(0,1280) scale(0.1,-0.1)" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="100">
<path class="path" d="M6125 12741 c-387 -139 -597 -254 -908 -495 -233 -181 -331 -236 -422 -236 -17 0 -69 11 -115 24 -115 33 -387 82 -540 97 -236 22 -573 0 -849 -56 -161 -33 -227 -39 -285 -25 -32 7 -108 48 -220 117 -381 238 -783 418 -1165 522 l-74 20 7 -87 c47 -605 193 -1137 396 -1443 l40 -60 -25 -65 c-38 -101 -93 -307 -116 -439 -18 -97 -22 -161 -23 -330 0 -213 11 -317 49 -441 26 -86 51 -79 -277 -76 -331 4 -697 -10 -1025 -38 -215 -19 -564 -59 -572 -66 -2 -2 -1 -9 2 -17 4 -11 27 -10 138 4 476 63 1214 101 1600 84 l167 -7 36 -87 c20 -47 55 -121 80 -163 l43 -77 -36 -5 c-20 -3 -92 -13 -161 -21 -513 -65 -1082 -183 -1506 -315 -194 -59 -234 -76 -234 -95 0 -8 1 -15 3 -15 2 0 57 18 122 40 266 90 566 168 900 234 276 55 413 76 891 141 l41 6 58 -77 c31 -42 88 -109 126 -149 l69 -72 -118 -43 c-265 -97 -648 -277 -882 -415 -179 -105 -370 -235 -370 -251 0 -8 4 -14 9 -14 4 0 69 40 142 89 339 225 742 426 1156 577 l93 33 93 -94 c214 -215 287 -380 287 -652 0 -260 -53 -544 -204 -1093 -70 -254 -124 -480 -156 -652 -157 -835 -108 -1553 159 -2358 89 -266 155 -431 312 -782 274 -611 310 -727 354 -1146 22 -205 36 -683 33 -1072 l-3 -345 -88 -7 c-109 -8 -232 -32 -290 -57 -66 -28 -111 -73 -143 -143 -26 -56 -29 -74 -29 -158 0 -74 4 -103 19 -129 67 -123 257 -196 611 -235 1310 -143 2603 -163 3865 -61 684 56 1558 169 1680 218 349 141 670 737 925 1721 185 712 354 1713 371 2201 24 650 -166 1275 -569 1880 -207 310 -356 484 -807 940 -477 483 -631 662 -805 935 -143 224 -273 537 -311 747 -35 198 -28 460 18 673 47 221 145 445 262 601 203 269 554 486 916 565 66 15 125 19 260 18 157 0 185 -3 274 -27 228 -61 359 -160 386 -292 26 -124 -55 -283 -190 -373 -135 -91 -278 -109 -464 -59 -131 35 -183 41 -236 27 -75 -19 -115 -52 -150 -124 -30 -61 -32 -71 -28 -144 6 -97 36 -158 119 -238 71 -67 209 -135 321 -158 99 -20 253 -20 358 0 267 50 581 244 737 454 209 281 260 673 133 1013 -70 186 -311 431 -525 533 -206 98 -593 140 -925 99 -549 -68 -1041 -298 -1400 -654 -243 -242 -405 -492 -496 -769 l-37 -113 -56 6 c-135 13 -486 25 -753 25 -271 0 -289 1 -284 18 44 150 60 274 60 457 0 244 -33 410 -129 650 l-44 109 49 66 c252 342 406 715 456 1103 22 176 12 628 -15 627 -3 -1 -78 -27 -166 -59z m709 -3021 c88 -6 161 -11 162 -13 1 -1 -6 -42 -17 -92 -25 -119 -49 -305 -49 -377 0 -32 -3 -58 -6 -58 -3 0 -63 13 -132 29 -251 58 -593 119 -872 156 -69 9 -135 18 -147 21 -21 4 -20 8 32 117 29 61 61 138 71 169 18 53 21 57 54 62 57 7 732 -3 904 -14z m-604 -436 c173 -28 390 -71 666 -131 20 -5 21 -13 28 -166 27 -621 177 -1043 583 -1650 253 -378 580 -768 1023 -1222 273 -279 343 -357 438 -484 238 -315 387 -652 453 -1019 72 -406 36 -1045 -97 -1712 -160 -804 -476 -1596 -709 -1772 -91 -69 -196 -83 -285 -38 -126 65 -154 220 -111 605 12 105 37 318 56 475 62 523 75 690 75 955 0 641 -136 1169 -474 1844 -344 687 -592 1023 -1179 1597 -293 287 -426 407 -721 653 -143 120 -297 251 -340 292 -240 224 -359 512 -373 899 -4 114 -2 159 11 210 21 86 73 186 148 288 54 75 64 83 87 79 46 -10 341 -136 516 -222 207 -101 374 -196 564 -322 107 -71 146 -92 154 -84 8 8 8 14 2 19 -364 252 -809 488 -1172 621 -40 15 -60 27 -56 35 4 6 41 61 84 121 42 61 88 131 103 156 l26 46 143 -19 c78 -10 239 -34 357 -54z"/>
</g>
</svg>
</div>
```

В этом примере SVG-элемент содержит один патч (`path`), но при этом видно, что прорисовка идет не от начальной точки и до конечной его пути, а одновременно в разных местах. Почему так происходит и от чего это зависит? Возможно ли разбить формулу одного патча на части и регулировать их очередность прорисовки? Интересует реализация такой анимации как при загрузке документа, так и при прокрутке страницы. Также интересует подробное описание обеих реализаций.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> В этом примере SVG-элемент содержит один патч (path), но при этом
> видно, что прорисовка идет не от начальной точки и до конечной его
> пути, а одновременно в разных местах. Почему так происходит и от чего
> это зависит?

Если присмотреться к формуле path, то можно заметить, что повторяются команды `zm`, что означает окончание одного подпатча `z` и начало второго подпатча `m` (moveto).

Препроцессор SVG выполняет команды `moveto` параллельно, рисуя как бы, несколькими перьями сразу. Из-за этого возникают некоторые неприятные нюансы.

Поясню на другом, более характерном примере:

Допустим задано время `dur="10s"`, реально анимация длится всего `4 сек`. Остальное время ничего не происходит.
И если за первой анимацией должна последовать вторая анимация, то возникает пауза равная `6сек`между анимациями. Пауза разработчиком приложения не предусмотрена и **крайне нежелательна** после окончания рисования линиями.
Это довольно распространенный эффект. Неважно в чем реализована анимация : Smil SVG или GSAP, либо в другом фреймворке JS, пауза наблюдается везде.

В примере ниже, если использовать `getTotalLength()`, то будет показана суммарная длина всех под-патчей - `4987px`

```js
var path = document.querySelector('#path1');
  var len = Math.round(path.getTotalLength() );
console.log("Длина пути - " + len);
```

```html
<svg width="588" height="588" viewBox="0 0 588 588" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path id="path1" d="M528.49 216.816L231.47 294.976L526.535 365.323V404.373L572.254 294L528.49 188.347V216.816ZM442.51 449.351L153.306 380.956V203.134L428.832 138.652L159.168 87.8455L87.6862 467.68L97.2454 490.755L262.441 559.18L442.51 449.351ZM502.83 500.745C502.554 501.157 502.242 501.539 501.89 501.89C501.539 502.242 501.157 502.554 500.745 502.83C500.33 503.105 499.896 503.338 499.438 503.53L296.894 587.426C296.436 587.615 295.962 587.758 295.474 587.854C294.989 587.95 294.498 588 294 588C293.502 588 293.011 587.95 292.526 587.854C292.038 587.758 291.564 587.615 291.106 587.426L88.5624 503.53C88.1044 503.338 87.6696 503.105 87.258 502.83C86.8431 502.554 86.4614 502.242 86.1096 501.89C85.7577 501.539 85.4457 501.157 85.1703 500.745C84.8948 500.33 84.6624 499.896 84.4699 499.438L0.574233 296.894C0.385039 296.436 0.242271 295.962 0.146014 295.477C0.0497582 294.989 0 294.498 0 294C0 293.502 0.0497582 293.011 0.146014 292.526C0.242271 292.038 0.385039 291.564 0.574233 291.106L84.4699 88.5625C84.6624 88.1044 84.8948 87.6696 85.1703 87.258C85.4457 86.8431 85.7577 86.4614 86.1096 86.1096C86.4614 85.761 86.8431 85.4457 87.258 85.1703C87.6696 84.8948 88.1044 84.6624 88.5624 84.4699L291.106 0.574233C291.564 0.385039 292.038 0.242321 292.526 0.146065C293.011 0.0498088 293.502 0 294 0C294.498 0 294.989 0.0498088 295.474 0.146065C295.962 0.242321 296.436 0.385039 296.894 0.574233L499.438 84.4699C499.896 84.6624 500.33 84.8948 500.745 85.1703C501.157 85.4457 501.539 85.761 501.89 86.1096C502.242 86.4614 502.554 86.8431 502.83 87.258C503.105 87.6696 503.338 88.1044 503.53 88.5625L587.426 291.106C587.615 291.564 587.758 292.038 587.854 292.526C587.95 293.011 588 293.502 588 294C588 294.498 587.95 294.989 587.854 295.477C587.758 295.962 587.615 296.436 587.426 296.894L503.53 499.438C503.338 499.896 503.105 500.33 502.83 500.745ZM15.7462 294L59.5096 399.653V188.347L15.7462 294Z" fill="none" stroke="#0091E2" stroke-width="2">
     <!-- Анимация рисования линий    -->
   <animate id="dash" attributeName="stroke-dasharray"  dur="10s" values="0,4987;4987,0" fill="freeze" />  
         <!-- Анимвация заполнения цветом -->
  <animate attributeName="fill"  dur="1s" begin="dash.end" values="white;#0091E2" fill="freeze"  />  
</path>

</svg>
```

В примере выше ярко наблюдается этот эффект, - после прорисовки линий возникает пауза до начала второй анимации - закраски.

Если преобразовать каждый под-патч в самосточтельный патч и замерить для каждого длину с помощью `getTotalLength()`, то получится:

```
<path id="path1" d="M528.49 ...216.816Z" />  ---- Длина пути - 912px
<path id="path2" d="M442.51 ...449.351Z" />  ---- Длина пути - 1834px
<path id="path3" d="M502.83 ...500.745Z" />  ---- Длина пути - 1801px
<path id="path4" d="M15.7462 ...294Z" />     ---- Длина пути - 440px
```

В сумме как раз `4987px`, как в сниппете выше

Поэтому становится понятна причина расхождения заданного времени анимации `10s` и реальной продолжительности анимации `4s`.
Анимация рисования происходит одновременно 4 линиями и вся анимация заканчивается после завершения рисования самого длинного патча `1834px`. На это уходит, как раз 4 секунды. Далее в оставшиеся `6s` ничего не происходит (пауза), так как уже всё нарисовано.
**Решение очевидно:**

Выбрать самый длинный подпатч -`1834px` - Это внешний контур фигуры и подставить его значение в команду анимации `stroke-dashoffset` Самый длинный подпатч будет прорисован и анимация заполнением цветом начнется без паузы:

```html
<svg width="588" height="588" viewBox="0 0 588 588" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path id="path1" d="M528.49 216.816L231.47 294.976L526.535 365.323V404.373L572.254 294L528.49 188.347V216.816ZM442.51 449.351L153.306 380.956V203.134L428.832 138.652L159.168 87.8455L87.6862 467.68L97.2454 490.755L262.441 559.18L442.51 449.351ZM502.83 500.745C502.554 501.157 502.242 501.539 501.89 501.89C501.539 502.242 501.157 502.554 500.745 502.83C500.33 503.105 499.896 503.338 499.438 503.53L296.894 587.426C296.436 587.615 295.962 587.758 295.474 587.854C294.989 587.95 294.498 588 294 588C293.502 588 293.011 587.95 292.526 587.854C292.038 587.758 291.564 587.615 291.106 587.426L88.5624 503.53C88.1044 503.338 87.6696 503.105 87.258 502.83C86.8431 502.554 86.4614 502.242 86.1096 501.89C85.7577 501.539 85.4457 501.157 85.1703 500.745C84.8948 500.33 84.6624 499.896 84.4699 499.438L0.574233 296.894C0.385039 296.436 0.242271 295.962 0.146014 295.477C0.0497582 294.989 0 294.498 0 294C0 293.502 0.0497582 293.011 0.146014 292.526C0.242271 292.038 0.385039 291.564 0.574233 291.106L84.4699 88.5625C84.6624 88.1044 84.8948 87.6696 85.1703 87.258C85.4457 86.8431 85.7577 86.4614 86.1096 86.1096C86.4614 85.761 86.8431 85.4457 87.258 85.1703C87.6696 84.8948 88.1044 84.6624 88.5624 84.4699L291.106 0.574233C291.564 0.385039 292.038 0.242321 292.526 0.146065C293.011 0.0498088 293.502 0 294 0C294.498 0 294.989 0.0498088 295.474 0.146065C295.962 0.242321 296.436 0.385039 296.894 0.574233L499.438 84.4699C499.896 84.6624 500.33 84.8948 500.745 85.1703C501.157 85.4457 501.539 85.761 501.89 86.1096C502.242 86.4614 502.554 86.8431 502.83 87.258C503.105 87.6696 503.338 88.1044 503.53 88.5625L587.426 291.106C587.615 291.564 587.758 292.038 587.854 292.526C587.95 293.011 588 293.502 588 294C588 294.498 587.95 294.989 587.854 295.477C587.758 295.962 587.615 296.436 587.426 296.894L503.53 499.438C503.338 499.896 503.105 500.33 502.83 500.745ZM15.7462 294L59.5096 399.653V188.347L15.7462 294Z" fill="none" stroke="#0091E2" stroke-width="2">
     <!-- Анимация рисования линий    -->
   <animate id="dash" attributeName="stroke-dasharray"  dur="10s" values="0,1834;1834,0" fill="freeze" />  
         <!-- Анимвация заполнения цветом -->
  <animate attributeName="fill"  dur="1s" begin="dash.end" values="white;#0091E2" fill="freeze"  />  
</path>

</svg>
```

Но если патчей много, то очень неудобно и трудоемко выбирать среди них самый длинный.

Чтобы автоматизировать эту задачу поиска и вывода самого длинного path, [**@Grundy♦**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy) создал очень полезный  скрипт:

```js
var path = document.querySelector('#path1');
var len = Math.round(path.getTotalLength());
console.log("Длина пути - " + len);

var paths = path.getAttribute('d')
  .match(/(M[^Z]+Z)/g)
  .map(p => {
    console.log(p); // добавлять надо было сюда
    const el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "path");
    el.setAttribute('d', p);
    return el.getTotalLength();
  });

console.log('пути', paths);
console.log('максимальная длина', Math.max(...paths));


var maxPath = path.getAttribute('d')
  .match(/(M[^Z]+Z)/g)
  .reduce((acc, p) => {
    const el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "path");
    el.setAttribute('d', p);
    var pathLength = el.getTotalLength();
    if (pathLength > acc.maxLength) {
      return {
        maxPath: p,
        maxLength: pathLength
      }
    }

    return acc;
  }, {
    maxPath: '',
    maxLength: 0
  });

console.log('максимальный путь с длинной', maxPath);
```

```html
<svg width="588" height="588" viewBox="0 0 588 588" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path id="path1" d="M528.49 216.816L231.47 294.976L526.535 365.323V404.373L572.254 294L528.49 188.347V216.816ZM442.51 449.351L153.306 380.956V203.134L428.832 138.652L159.168 87.8455L87.6862 467.68L97.2454 490.755L262.441 559.18L442.51 449.351ZM502.83 500.745C502.554 501.157 502.242 501.539 501.89 501.89C501.539 502.242 501.157 502.554 500.745 502.83C500.33 503.105 499.896 503.338 499.438 503.53L296.894 587.426C296.436 587.615 295.962 587.758 295.474 587.854C294.989 587.95 294.498 588 294 588C293.502 588 293.011 587.95 292.526 587.854C292.038 587.758 291.564 587.615 291.106 587.426L88.5624 503.53C88.1044 503.338 87.6696 503.105 87.258 502.83C86.8431 502.554 86.4614 502.242 86.1096 501.89C85.7577 501.539 85.4457 501.157 85.1703 500.745C84.8948 500.33 84.6624 499.896 84.4699 499.438L0.574233 296.894C0.385039 296.436 0.242271 295.962 0.146014 295.477C0.0497582 294.989 0 294.498 0 294C0 293.502 0.0497582 293.011 0.146014 292.526C0.242271 292.038 0.385039 291.564 0.574233 291.106L84.4699 88.5625C84.6624 88.1044 84.8948 87.6696 85.1703 87.258C85.4457 86.8431 85.7577 86.4614 86.1096 86.1096C86.4614 85.761 86.8431 85.4457 87.258 85.1703C87.6696 84.8948 88.1044 84.6624 88.5624 84.4699L291.106 0.574233C291.564 0.385039 292.038 0.242321 292.526 0.146065C293.011 0.0498088 293.502 0 294 0C294.498 0 294.989 0.0498088 295.474 0.146065C295.962 0.242321 296.436 0.385039 296.894 0.574233L499.438 84.4699C499.896 84.6624 500.33 84.8948 500.745 85.1703C501.157 85.4457 501.539 85.761 501.89 86.1096C502.242 86.4614 502.554 86.8431 502.83 87.258C503.105 87.6696 503.338 88.1044 503.53 88.5625L587.426 291.106C587.615 291.564 587.758 292.038 587.854 292.526C587.95 293.011 588 293.502 588 294C588 294.498 587.95 294.989 587.854 295.477C587.758 295.962 587.615 296.436 587.426 296.894L503.53 499.438C503.338 499.896 503.105 500.33 502.83 500.745ZM15.7462 294L59.5096 399.653V188.347L15.7462 294Z" fill="none" stroke="#0091E2" stroke-width="2">
     <!-- Анимация рисования линий    -->
   <animate id="dash" attributeName="stroke-dasharray"  dur="10s" values="0,4987;4987,0" fill="freeze" />  
         <!-- Анимвация заполнения цветом -->
  <animate attributeName="fill"  dur="1s" begin="dash.end" values="white;#0091E2" fill="freeze"  />  
</path>

</svg>
```